# Building a "balanced" universal set

Tags: ds.algorithms, co.combinatorics, expanders, extremal-combinatorics

A set of length $n$ binary vectors $\mathcal{U}=\{u_1,..,u_r\}$ is called *$(n,k)$-universal* if for all $S\subset [n], |S|=k$, $|\mathcal{U}_{|S}|=2^k$, i.e. for every subset of indices of size $k$, all $2^k$ vectors appear in $\mathcal{U}$'s vectors when restricted to $S$.

A $(n,k)$-universal set is said to be $(T,\alpha)$-balanced if for every vector $v$ of length k and every subset $S\subset [n], |S|=k$, the number of vectors in $\mathcal{U}$ which has $v$ in indices $S$ is at least $\frac{T}{\alpha}$ and at most $T\cdot \alpha$. The original definition of the universal set only ensures that there exists at least one such vector $u\in \mathcal{U}$.

Related works for similar structures are:

1. [Nearly optimal build of $(n,k)$-universal set](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.74.5859&rep=rep1&type=pdf) (NSS).
2. [Nearly optimal build of $\delta$-balanced perfect hashing family](http://www.tau.ac.il/~nogaa/PDFS/bhash3.pdf) by Alon and Gunter.
3. [Simple Constructions of Almost k-wise Independent Random Variables](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.106.6442) (AGHP).

**My question is: is it possible to deterministically build a *small* $(T,\alpha)$-balanced  universal set?**

(By small, I mean $O(2^{k+\text{polylog}(k,\alpha)}\cdot \text{poly}(n))$).

It doesn't seem hard to show (using the probabilistic method) that such set exist, but I'm interested in explicit build.

Comment: Isn't an $(n,k)$-universal set merely a range space with VC dimension at least $k$ ? the elements of the range space are the "dimensions" and the ranges are the bit vectors interpreted as characteristic vectors ?

Comment: @SureshVenkat VC dimension at least $k$ only implies that there exists some set $S$ of size $k$ which is shattered. Here the requirement is that every set of size $k$ is shattered.

Comment: @SashoNikolov is correct. When I first saw universal sets that was also my first thought, bit they're quite different.

Comment: Why doesn't what you need follow from the AGHP results, by setting $\epsilon = \alpha 2^{-k}$ in their max-norm almost $k$-wise independence construction?

Comment: oh duh. sorry. got my quantifiers mixed up.